# how does this loop sequence flows

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-operator

I came across a qns which sums the in between of both numbers if they are not equal to each other, I don't quite understand how the statement in the while loop works.

**e.g a = 4, b = 0 
the end value of sum should be 10 as it is 4+3+2+1+0 = 10**

```
function getSum (a,b)
{
 var sum = 0;

  while (a !== b)
{
  sum += a < b ? a++:b++;
}
 return sum+a
}
```

Am i suppose to see it as

**(sum+=a) <  b** ? a++:b++

OR

sum += **(a < b) ? a++:b++**

where the conditions are the ones in bold

(edit : I know the conditions is before the **?** for the second part just trying to make it clearer if i were to follow through the loop, am i suppose to do the ones in bold first as I got lost despite writing it down in pen and paper)

If anyone can teach / help break down the loop sequence step by step, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `+=` is an assignment operation, it is one of the last operations to be executed. Therefore, 
`sum += (a < b) ? a++:b++` is the correct equivalent.

This line is equivalent to:

```
if (a<b) {
  sum += a++;
}
else {
  sum += b++;
}
```